# insert into using values and select from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Want to add service from second to first table if keyword is found in the first table. Also, while inserting want to add some other values into first table.

I have this query :

```
$sql="insert into `firsttable`
    (
      `time`,
      `content`,
      `number`,
      `service`
    )
    values
    (
      '$date',
      '$message',
      '$number',
      (select   service
        from secondtable
        where keyword='$keyword'
      )
    );";
```

should have WHERE at the end ??

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What is your question exactly? It seems a bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

You can use literal values in the select list:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `firsttable` " .
        "(`time`, `content`, `number`, `service`) " .
        "SELECT '$date', '$message', '$number', service " .
        "FROM secondtable " .
        "WHERE keyword = '$keyword'";
```

Mandatory comment:
Using variable replacement inside a string leaves your code susceptible to SQL-injection attacks. It's a much better practice to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: yes but i should take only service from second table

Comment: @dongou look at the quotes - the other fields are the literals supplied from outside, which are added to every `service` selected from `secondtable`.

Comment: hmmm it does not work

Comment: @dongou care to elaborate?

Comment: nevermind, i solved my problem :) 
My "question query" works well but i had some errors in characters in the query lol :)
thank you by the way